# Auto Updater for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, auto-update

Am I allowed to do an auto-updater for my WP8.1 app?  If so how is it possible?

Or, am I limited to the App Store way of updating my app?

I have just started to embrace WP8.1 so I a still a newbie.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you developed the app , then yes , you have to update it through store.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg442301(v=vs.105).aspx

For the apps you have installed from store, you can enable settings to update apps automatically.

http://www.windowscentral.com/do-you-automatically-update-your-apps-windows-phone-81